# How to test my redux saga spawn code block

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga

i want to test spawn block using jest...i created a generator in beforeEach block and i'm checking through
generator.next() function, like this

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        generator = saga.postCompare();
    });
```

and my code like this

```
    export function* LoadData() {
      let someVariable;
      try {
       for (let index = 0; index < 3; index += 1) {
            yield spawn(loadUserData, varaiable1, variable2);
       }
     }
   }

   export function* loadUserData(Prop1, Prop2) {
      try {
        const userData = yield call(serverManager.fetch1,prop1, prop2 );
        const isUserSelected = yield* isUserSelected();
        if (!isUserSelected) {
          return;
        }
        yield put(
          Actions.onRequestSucceededForUser(userData.data.value, prop1),
        );
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to test spawn block using jest

Maybe most straightforward solution is accepted for testing `redux-saga` generators - just by definition how they works, and without mocking anything. So, every `saga` is just generator function, which yields control flow to parent function at every `yield` operator. Also, `saga-effects` in facts does nothing - just create special form object, which is acceptable by `redux-saga` internal process manager (https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/io.js )

So, you can easily run under-test `saga` function from test runner, and perform assertions for returned actions, like this:

```
const saga = LoadData();
assert(saga.next()).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(loadUserData, varaiable1, variable2))
assert(saga.next()).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(loadUserData, varaiable1, variable2))
assert(saga.next()).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(loadUserData, varaiable1, variable2))
```

In this way function `loadUserData` will not be executed, and also effects descriptor objects will be created