# How to use sinon unit test redux saga spawn function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-redux, sinon, redux-saga

I'm stuck on my redux-saga call with spawn call unit test, need someone extra help, big thanks!

My saga

```
export function* sampleTest() {
    try {
        yield put(someData1);
        yield spawn(someData2);
        yield spawn(someData3);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
}
}

someData2 code is an API call this one returns an array with one object.
```

My test

```
describe('For my spawn test', () => {
    it('Initialize saga', () => {
        const someData2Spy = sinon.spy();
        const gen = sampleTest({});
        expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(put(someData1));
      expect(gen.next(someData2Spy).value).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(someData2));  <--- Does not work
        // expect(gen.next()).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(someData3));  <--- Does not work
        // expect(gen.next().done).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

I will get an error for

```
Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
```

or

```
Tried expect(gen.next()).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(someData2)); get this error: 
expected { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) } to equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) }
```

And I tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504563/how-to-test-my-redux-saga-spawn-code-block) does not work for me.
Thank you

Comment: Would you mind to show what type of function is the  `someData2` and `someData3`?

Comment: Also, might start to help solve the issue, but when you `expect(gen.next(someData2Spy).value).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(someData2))`, maybe you could change to `expect(gen.next().value).to.be.equal(spawn(someData2))` and see if it works?

Comment: someData2 and someData2 are some API call. I tried this `expect(gen.next().value).to.be.equal(spawn(someData2))` have this error `expected { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) } to equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) }`

Comment: Updated my question, thank you so much

Comment: Hmm, weird. Is the block `{ Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) }` exactly the same in both?

Comment: Yes, that what is show up for me, and I remove `deep.equal` to be `to.be.equal` but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out this work for me now:

```
describe('For my spawn test', () => {
  it('Initialize saga', () => {
    expect(gen.next({}).value).to.deep.equal(put(someData1));
    expect(gen.next({}).value).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(someData2));
    expect(gen.next({}).value).to.be.deep.equal(spawn(someData3));
 });
});
```

Thanks for the help!